# Error numérico en PosgresSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

hace un tiempo me surgió un problema en PostgreSQL, antes veía los números de DNI por ejemplo 55.555.555, hasta ahí todo bien, ahora cuando hago la consulta me lo trae asi 55,555.555
No se por que me lo empezó a separar con una coma, busque todas las formas y no puedo cambiar por un punto.
Si alguien me pude dar una mano.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola, intenta adjuntar fotos de como te sale y como quieres que se vea, eso puede ayudar a entender mejor el problema, ahora, has visto si ha cambiado depronto la codificacion de la base de datos?

Comment: Hola Kevin, no se si cambio la codificación, tendria que ver por ahi, no?

Comment: Puede ser, normalmente se usa el utf-8 o un formato de codificacion parecido, seria que revisaras y mires cual tienes

Comment: Claro, el tema que estoy acostumbrado a tocar SQL, Postgres no la tengo muy clara y no se bien don ver y modificar eso.

Comment: Intenta con este SELECT * FROM information_schema.character_sets;

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: @KevinRestrepo LATIN1 tiene configurado

Comment: Intenta cambiarla por utf-8 a ver si te funciona

Comment: Eso es muy probablemente cuestión de configuración del cliente. No sabemos que estés usando para conectarte a la base de datos, pero es cuestión de visualización y configuración del sistema local.

Comment: Tambien lo que dice luis, puedes mirar en la configuracion regional, como tienen la separacion de miles que normalmente es por comas, podria ser una opcion